# JPQL: Problem with the following WHERE-Clause using Inheritance

Tags: java, sql, jpa, where-clause, jpql

I'm using the following query, for getting all Fruits that are linked with the User.

```
return (List<Fruit>) getEm()
            .createQuery(
                    "SELECT DISTINCT f FROM Fruit f, User u WHERE (f = u.apples OR f = u.oranges OR f = u.mangos) AND u.id = :id")
            .setParameter("id", id).getResultList();
```

The corresponding Entities are the following:

```
public class Fruit{

private int id;
```

}

```
public class User{

private int id;
private Collection<Apple> apples;
private Collection<Orange> oranges;
private Collection<Mango> mangos;
```

}

```
public class Mango extends Fruit{

private int id;
...
```

}

```
public class Apple extends Fruit{

private int id;
...
```

}

```
public class Orange extends Fruit{

private int id;
...
```

}

The problem is, that the above mentioned query dont give me a result if any of the Collections dont exist for the user. So if a user has no apples, i dont get 0 as the result. I already tried to catch errors with statements like u.apples IS NOT EMPTY, etc. but it doenst work either.

So, could you give me a tipp for this case? The whole thing would be easier, if the Fruit would have a one-to-many relation to the user, but unfortunatelly i cant afford this for the program...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your JPQL is not valid, so I'm not sure how it works at all.

You can only use the "." notation on a ToOne not a ToMany, for a ToMany you need to use a join.  For a join you can use an outer join to allow none.

```
SELECT DISTINCT f FROM Fruit f, User u left join u.apples a ... WHERE f = a or ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Suspect you want IN and not =, but phrases like "cant afford this for the program" make me nervous that there's a lot of hacked stuff going on.